# Analyse First Order ODE with no exact olution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that to solve a first order linear inhomogeneous ODE you apply an integrating factor. What if the integrating factor is a function for which no integral in terms of elementary functions exists (according to Mathematica, say). What is the next step to finding properties of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the equation, but one thing you might look at is using
 [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) to get bounds on the solution.